# Woocommerce shop page (category page template) Add to cart button behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make category page (shop page) to have custom button that links to single product page instead of standard [Add to cart] behavior.

This below is my code but the link on the button called by theme defined shortcode with an link variable `$link`. But instead of taking user to single product page it takes user back to the same opened shop page.

What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('[us_btn text="Details" link="' . $link . '" size="12px" align="right" icon="fal|info-circle"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with your developer tools if your link href is filled with product URL, it may be empty if it takes you back to the same page.
The shortcode must be the issue if it is not well rendered.

Comment: you are right. Something seems to be wrong with my $link variable. developer tools shows this: `<a class="w-btn style_solid color_primary icon_atleft" href="" style="font-size:12px;"><i class="fal fa-info-circle"></i><span class="w-btn-label">Details</span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Had to strip `http://` from link

```
echo do_shortcode('[us_btn text="Details" link="url:' . str_replace("http://", "", $link) . '" size="12px" align="right" icon="fas|info-circle"]');
```